# jQuery Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an Image Slider from jQuery from this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtYP_eSVKfs.

I've just finished the second part - building the automatic image slideshow. The result should be that the images loop through from 1 to 4 and then back again while fading in and out.

However, when I load the page the first image fades in but the loop doesn't start. The first image just remains on the display.

I'm guessing it's something to do with my startSlider function but I can't find the problem. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <img id="1" src="images/image1.jpg">
        <img id="2" src="images/image2.jpg">
        <img id="3" src="images/image3.jpg">
        <img id="4" src="images/image4.jpg">
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="left">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">Next</a>


</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

#slider > img {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}

a.left {
    float: left;
}

a.right {
    float: right;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
var sliderInt = 1;
var sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider > img#1').fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider() {
    count = $('#slider > img').length();

    if(sliderNext > count) {
        sliderNext = 1;
        sliderInt = 1;
    }

    loop = setInterval(function() {
        $('#slider > img').fadeOut(300);
        $('#slider > img#' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

    }, 3000);

}
```

Comment: length not length()

Answer (score 0):

`length` not `length()` ,place the if in the setInterval function

```js
var sliderInt = 1;
var sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider > img#1').fadeIn(300);
  startSlider();
});

function startSlider() {
  count = $('#slider > img').length;


  loop = setInterval(function() {
    $('#slider > img').fadeOut(300);
    $('#slider > img#' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;
    if (sliderNext > count) {
      sliderNext = 1;
      sliderInt = 1;
    }


  }, 3000);

}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#slider {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
#slider > img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}
a.left {
  float: left;
}
a.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slider">
    <img id="1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <img id="2" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/">
    <img id="3" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/">
    <img id="4" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/">
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="left">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="right">Next</a>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting length you should use length not length()

count = $('#slider > img').length(); // wrong

count = $('#slider > img').length; //correct